# warning: definition of implicit copy constructor even though I didn't call copy constructor

Tags: c++

I am trying to run this example in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment, but when I delete the default constructor and default copy constructor: `A() = default; A(A const&) = default;`, clang++ says that `warning: definition of implicit copy constructor for 'A' is deprecated because it has a user-provided copy assignment operator [-Wdeprecated-copy-with-user-provided-copy]`.

My question is that I have called copy assignment instead of copy constructor, why clang++ reports copy constructor warning?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
 
struct A
{
    int n;
    std::string s1;

    // user-defined copy assignment (copy-and-swap idiom)
    A& operator=(A other)
    {
        std::cout << "copy assignment of A\n";
        std::swap(n, other.n);
        std::swap(s1, other.s1);
        return *this;
    }
};
 
int main()
{
    A a1, a2;
    std::cout << "a1 = a2 calls ";
    a1 = a2; // user-defined copy assignment
}
```

Here is [cppinsight link](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=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&insightsOptions=cpp17&std=cpp17&rev=1.0), I can see there is an inline copy constructor in struct A.

```
struct A
{
  int n;
  std::basic_string<char> s1;
  inline A & operator=(A other)
  {
    std::operator<<(std::cout, "copy assignment of A\n");
    std::swap(this->n, other.n);
    std::swap(this->s1, other.s1);
    return *this;
  }
  
  // inline A(const A &) noexcept(false) = default;
  // inline ~A() noexcept = default;
  // inline A() noexcept = default;
};
```

Comment: The comment says "copy-and-swap idiom", there must be a reason for that...

Comment: Some helpful reading: [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)

Comment: The inline copy constructor is commented out

Comment: To delete as stated in the question the default destructor (really?) and default copy constructor you should use `=delete` instead of `=default`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This invokes A's copy constructor since `other` is a value copy.

```
inline A & operator=(A other)
```

Change it to

```
inline A & operator=(const A& other)
```

Then drop the swaps and simply assign other's member variables to *this

```
n=other.n;
s1=other.s1;
```

This removes the requirement for a copy constructor. However, defining an assignment operator w/o also defining a copy constructor violates the rule of three hence the compiler warning. Also, "inline" is intrinsic when the member function is defined in the class.

Comment: They're looking to use a [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom), so I'm guessing the copy and the swap is desired.

Comment: the reason of the error is described correctly, but the suggestion should be "put the copy constructor back".

Comment: It looked like the OP didn't understand copy and swap requires the copy constructor so, since the assignment operator can be implemented w/o  ctor, it would be useful for learning to remove the requirement. Baby steps.